# What is the purpose of using prototype and static method in this factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I really do not understand about the main purpose of using "Static Method" and "Instance Methods(prototype)" in "preloader factory"(AngularJS) that Ben coded in the following link.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm

I know how the prototype and constructor work but I never seen the real action in function like this. Why not just put all the code in a function without using prototype and static method?

Can anybody help me to understand this?

Thanks!

```
app.factory(
        "preloader",
        function( $q, $rootScope ) {

            function Preloader( imageLocations ) {
                // All the initial variables, deferred and promise here.
            }


            // ---
            // STATIC METHODS.
            // ---

            Preloader.preloadImages = function( imageLocations ) {
                var preloader = new Preloader( imageLocations );
                return( preloader.load() );
            };

            // ---
            // INSTANCE METHODS.
            // ---

            Preloader.prototype = {
                // public methods and private methods here

            };

            return( Preloader );
        }
    );
```

Comment: Maybe because the static methods are being used in forming the angular module, the instance methods will be used by the users ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you don't *have* to use a prototype patten in order to achieve this. However, doing this gives you a solid design patten that applies to this particular (and most others) really well. Also when making `Preloader` into a class like this, it now becomes lot easier to extract this into a library and use in other projects if you wish.

So lets dig into why use a constructor, a static method, and a instance method (in prototype).  The answer involves, understanding of classic [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) more than this particular example.

`preloadImages` static method: Static method is shared across all objects, which means it is used to do tasks that are common to all objects you may want to create for the class `PreLoader`. In this case, static method 'preLoadImages' is just creating a new Instance of it's own class, passing it all image locations to load, and then returns a `promise` which can be used to track if all images were loaded.

`this`: any properties they the author creates in the constructor and assigns to `this` are basically *instance variables* are are unique to each object.

```
function Preloader( imageLocations ) {
     ....
     // I keep track of the current state of the preloader.
     this.state = this.states.PENDING;
     ....
}
```

`prototype`: In JavaScript any functions that are added to the 'prototype' object are instance methods, meaning they act individually on the object they are invoked with. A prototype method typically gets access to `this` object using which it can create, modify or return instance variables. 
For example, `isInitiated` method the author adds to the prototype is checking the `this.state` of the class `PreLoader` and returning it, so it can be used in the application.

```
Preloader.prototype = {
   isInitiated: function isInitiated() {
       return( this.state !== this.states.PENDING );
    }
}
```

So **why** make Preloader into a class? After all its static method is invoking its own controller and creating just one object!

Seems counter intuitive at first.  but when you think about how you would use image pre-loader on a typical application, it does make sense.  Typically you would like to use `Preloader` on multiple sets of images across the page or the application. Also `factory` in angular returns a `singleton`, and Preloader now conforms to those standards.

To do this now the author doesn't have to repeat the code, but just create another Preloader and start working with it. Its now self contained. Gives progress reports, tells when its done, etc..

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your response. It all makes sense. I have one thing i dont understand the term you said, "controller" in the following sentence. "After all its static method is invoking its own controller and creating just one object!" What is it?